# How to Save Variables from a Matlab Matfile to Individual Structures within that Matfile

Tags: arrays, matlab, data-structures

I have a matfile with multiple data variables from different test cases such that the matfile would be for example:

```
zzz.mat
```

And the data within is listed as:

```
C1_jjj
C1_lll
C1_ggg

C2_jjj
C2_lll
C2_ggg
```

Where `jjj`, `lll`, `ggg` are representing the variable name, and `C1` and `C2` are different Case numbers.

I would like to rewrite and save the matfile such that I break up each test Case variable (C1 and C2) as their own structures within the matfile.  Therefore the matfile, zzz.mat would now read:

```
C1(structure)
C2(structure)
```

where C1 and C2 contain each variable (jjj, lll, ggg) from each test performed.

Any thoughts on how to restructure this?

Comment: Sequential variable names (`C1` `C2`) are rarely a good idea. I would use a cell or array instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should go one step further and use an array of structs.  Your matfile will contain a single variable, and `C(1).jjj` is an example of what it looks like to refer to a variable.
The basic idea is to load the matfile as a struct (to get an easy list of variables), then convert the form of the struct to something more readable using dynamic field references.

```
C = struct;

% Load MATFILE into a single structure containing all the variables.
S = load('zzz.mat');

% Loop over fields of S, which is the same as
%    variable names in the MATFILE
fn = fieldnames(S);
for ii = 1:length(fn)
    f = fn{ii};  % original variable name, C1_jjj for exammple

    % Extract case number and variable name from the string.
    % Edit this if your variable names are different from
    % the examples given
    tokens = regexp(f, 'C(\d+)_(\w+)', 'tokens');
    case_number = str2num(tokens{1}{1});
    var_name = tokens{1}{2};

    % Insert the value of the field into the new structure
    %   using dynamic fieldnames
    C(case_number).(var_name) = S.(f);
end
```